# Consecutive `PlotStyle` across multiple plots

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

### Problem

I would like to use consecutive `PlotStyle`s (e.g. from `ColorData[...]`) across different `Plot`/`ListPlot`/`ListLinePlot` commands. That is: each plot should pick colors from the list starting where the previous plot stopped.

In other words:
I want

```
Show[
 Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, ... , PlotStyle -> cs],
 Plot[{h[x], i[x]}, ... , PlotStyle -> cs]
]
```

to be equivalent to

```
Plot[{f[x], g[x], h[x], i[x]}, ... , PlotStyle -> cs]
```

But I still want to have the same automatic color schemes for e.g. `Show[Plot[...], ListPlot[...]]`.

---

### First attempt

Since the `PlotStyle -> ColorData[n]` options seems to call `ColorData[n][k]` with increasing index `k`, I created a wrapper to make sure that `k` always increases:

```
ic[n0_Integer: 0, n1_Integer: 0, f_Function: Identity] := 
 Module[{N0 = n0, N1 = n1},
  (If[# <= N1, N0 = N0 + N1]; N1 = #; f[N0 + #]) &
 ]
```

Now

```
c = ic[];
Table[c[n], {n, 1, 5}]
Table[c[n], {n, 1, 5}]
```

returns

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
{6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
```

And I can do the same with indexed `ColorDataFunction`s like so `color = ic[ColorData[n][#] &]`. Repeated calls of `color[1]` will return consecutive colors.

But repeated `Plot[..., PlotStyle -> color]` will always restart from the beginning.

Comment: works as expected if you use `PlotStyle->color[1]`

Comment: @kglr Not for me. See the edit. `PlotStyle -> color[1]` will only give different colors for different `Plot[...]` calls, not for different functions within a single `Plot[...]`.

Comment: With multiple functions (say 2)  using `PlotStyle->Table[color[1],{2}]` works for both within and across plots.

Comment: @kglr Yes, it does. But it needs redundant a-priori knowledge about the number of functions in the `PlotStyle` option, which is one of the things I am trying to avoid.

Comment: DLichti, i posted an alternative approach that doesn't require knowledge of how many functions/lists appear in the first argument of plot/listplot...

Answer (score 5):

You can use `color` to define a function `style` and wrap the first argument of plot/chart functions with `style` to get the colors updated both within and across plots:

```
ClearAll[color, style]
color = ic[(ColorData[3][#] &)];
style = Style[#, color[1]]& /@ #&;

Show[Plot[Evaluate@style@{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2Pi}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"], 
   Plot[Evaluate @ style @ {x Sin[x], x Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2Pi}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"],
   PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
color = ic[(ColorData[3][#] &)];
Plot[Evaluate @ style @ {Sin[x], Cos[x], x Sin[x], x Cos[x]}, {x,0, 2Pi},
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Another example:

```
color = ic[(ColorData[43][#] &)];
style = Style[#,color[1]]&/@#&;
```

The first execution of

```
Row[{Plot[Evaluate @ style @ {Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  BaseStyle -> Thick, ImageSize->200]
ListLinePlot[style @ RandomReal[1, {2, 10, 2}], 
 BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large], ImageSize->200]
PieChart[style @ Range[3], ImageSize->200]}]
```

gives

[image]

the second and third executions give

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hm, I really hoped, this would be possible without messing with the first argument. Now, the `style` function will evaluate the first argument before `Plot` can extract the informations for `PlotLegends -> "Expressions"`. Is there a way to keep the argument of `style` unevaluated?

Comment: @DLichti, afaik we do need `Evaluate` when the function arguments are wrapped. In older versions (e.g. version 9)  you could use a function for `PlotStyle`. So `Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, Pi}, PlotStyle -> ({clock[1],#}&/@#&)]` would give the desired result. But in versions 11+  this trick no longer works.