# Recolour existing plots

Tags: plotting, graphics

**Context**

More often than not I end up doing plots one after the other so that I have a set of plots with the same colour style.
When I want to make it more publishable ready, I would like to reassign colours to each line.

> How to assign colours from a given style to existing sets of plots?

**Example**

```
pl1= Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,4Pi}];
pl2= Plot[Cos[2x],{x,0,4Pi}];
Show[pl1,pl2];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Attempt**

I while back I wrote the following function

```
Clear[ShowColor];
ShowColor[list___]:=ShowColor[{list}]/; Length[{list}]>1;
ShowColor[list_,ColorRange->color__,opt___]:= Module[{len=Length[list]},
     Table[list[[i]] /. RGBColor[_,_,_]->
          GradientColor[color][(i-1)/(len-1)],{i,len}]//Show[#,opt]&]
ShowColor[list_,opt___]:= Module[{len=Length[list]},
     Table[list[[i]] /. RGBColor[_,_,_]->
          GradientColor[ColorData[10] /@ Range[10]][(i-1)/(len-1)],{i,len}]//Show[#,opt]&]
```

which uses the [GradientColor](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/4193/) Package,
so that

```
ShowColor[{pl1,pl2}]
```

produces

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But I am left with the impression that it could be done more elegantly and generally with the modern version of Mathematica, making use of the set of default styles 
and working in harmony with other features.

Also, my implementation is not very robust. For instance,

```
 Show[pl1, pl2] // ShowColor
```

fails.

What would be great would be to have a function which 
e.g. would take standard Options such as

```
 ShowColor[plots,PlotStyle-> ColorData[10]]
```

or

```
  ShowColor[plots,PlotStyle-> Directive[{Dashed,Blue}]]
```

> Any suggestion on how to make this as generic as possible?

Thanks!

Comment: you might find [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/199921/125)  interesting.

Comment: thanks for the link

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using DLichti's ingenious idea / function from [this q/a](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/199921/125):

```
dLichtiIncrement[n0_Integer: 0, n1_Integer: 0, f_Function: Identity] := 
  Module[{N0 = n0, N1 = n1}, (If[# <= N1, N0 = N0 + N1]; N1 = #; f[N0 + #]) & ]
```

to define a function `color` which increments the color every time it is invoked as `color[1]`:

```
ClearAll[color, reColor]
color = dLichtiIncrement[(ColorData[97][#] &)];
reColor[] = # /. _?ColorQ :> color[1] &;
reColor[_] := Module[{}, ClearAll[color]; 
  color = dLichtiIncrement[(ColorData[97][#] &)]; reColor[]]
```

**Examples:**

```
pl1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}];
pl2 = Plot[Cos[2 x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}];
Show[pl1, pl2]//reColor[]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4Pi}, {y, 0, 4Pi}] // reColor[]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{x Sin[x], x Cos[x], Sin[x Cos[x]]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", Filling -> Axis, FillingStyle -> Opacity[.5]] // reColor[]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[Sum[Sin[RandomReal[5, 2].{x, y}], {5}]], {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5},
 PlotTheme -> "Monochrome"] // reColor[]
```

[image]

```
 ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi},
    ContourShading -> False] // reColor[]
```

[image]

You can also use `color[1]` in setting `ChartStyle`/`PlotStyle`:

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}}, ChartStyle -> Table[color[1], 3]]
```

[image]

Using `reColor[blah] @ Red` resets `color[1]` to its initial state:

```
 reColor[blah] @ Red == ColorData[97][1]
```

> True

Comment: This is almost perfect: would it be possible to give reColor an argument to allow for the colours to reincrement from the beginning? I.e. plots//reColor[] would yield the same sets of colours ?

Comment: @chris, i made small changes to allow resetting: regular call is `reColor[]` and `reColor[anything]` resets `color` to its initial definition.

Comment: Great ! I modified it slightly to choose the ColourTable: `ClearAll[color, reColor]
color = dLichtiIncrement[(ColorData[10][#] &)];
reColor[] = # /. _?ColorQ :> color[1] &;
reColor[val_: 10] := Module[{}, ClearAll[color];
  color = dLichtiIncrement[(ColorData[val][#] &)]; reColor[]]`

Comment: The only remaining question is : are you nostalgic of the 70ies ? :-)

Comment: ... those were the days:)

Answer (score 4):

A simple way is to pass the coordinates in the plots to `ListLinePlot`.

```
recolor[plot_, opts___] := ListLinePlot[
  Cases[plot, Line[coords_] :> coords, Infinity],
  opts
  ]

Show[
 recolor[pl1, PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Dashed]],
 recolor[pl2, PlotStyle -> Red]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It can also be used to recolor already combined plots:

```
recolor[
 Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[2 x]}, {x, 0, 4 Pi}],
 PlotStyle -> {
   Directive[Blue, Dashed],
   Red
   }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And it also works on this:

```
recolor[pl3=Show[pl1, pl2],
 PlotStyle -> {
   Directive[Blue, Dashed],
   Red
   }]
```

You can also use existing themes:

```
  recolor[pl3, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @chris that's always a good idea, you never know what someone might come up with.

Comment: Thanks again for your solution: I would have accepted both if I could.